# Currency.getSymbol() returning "US$"

Tags: java, locale, currency

On one instance of Windows Server 2016 the call:

```
// locale is "en_US"
Currency.getInstance(locale).getSymbol();
```

Is returning "US$" instead of "$". Why would this happen?

To add a comment I put below:

This is happening because the system is in Canada (thank you to the commenters). But in Canada the currency symbol is also the "$" so my question is - why is it assuming a $ is US$ and not CDN$ or $?

Comment: Why don't you just read the javadoc? Your exact situation is explained in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol--

Comment: I was not aware that it was dependent on the default locale too (which is what I take from reading the link you sent). Makes sense though - thank you.

Comment: @JBNizet - Ok, this is what's happening as the system is in Canada. But in Canada the currency symbol is also the "$" so my question is - why is it assuming a $ is US$ and not CDN$?

Comment: Because you're asking the currency for the locale "en_US", and the javadoc of the method says: "Returns the Currency instance for the country of the given locale". In the US, they use the US $.

Answer (score 0):

> the symbol is "$" if the default locale is the US, while for other
>   locales it may be "US$". If no symbol can be determined, the ISO 4217
>   currency code is returned.

Copied from the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol--). I suspect that even though you say that locale is US, that might not be true, so it might be worth checking the earlier code

Comment: Ok, this is what's happening as the system is in Canada. But in Canada the currency symbol is also the "$" so my question is - why is it assuming a $ is US$ and not CDN$?

Comment: maybe the API takes "$" as US$ by default? i'm just speculating because I don't have much experience with the Currency class